# Prove that PM is perpendicular to LN

Tags: geometry

[image]

There is a triangle PQR, in which L, M and N are the midpoints of the side PQ, QR, PR respectively. L and N are joined. P and M are joined.

How do I prove that PM is perpendicular to LN ?

Using midpoint theorem.

I tried but I'm stuck in the middle.

Can I say that as M divides the side QR into two, so that the angle PMR and PMQ are 90 degrees?

Comment: From markings triangle is isosceles, PQ=PR. So yes angles you mention are 90.

Answer (score 0):

The way you answer questions like this typically depends on what theorems you're allowed to assume as being already known.  Here, for instance, $\ \vert PQ\vert = \vert PR\vert\ $, so the the triangle $\ PQR\ $ is isosceles. You could therefore use the theorem that the line $\ PM\ $ from the vertex $\ P\ $ to the mid-point $\ M\ $ of $\ QR\ $ must be be perpendicular to $\ QR\ $. However, in writing out the proof you would need to state explicitly that the conclusion follows from fact that $\ PQR\ $ is isosceles, because it would not hold otherwise.

If the theorem just cited is not one you're not allowed to assume as already known, it's nevertheless easy enough to prove by showing that triangles $\ PQM\ $ and $\ PRM\ $ are congruent (because they have three equal sides, $\ \vert PQ\vert = \vert PR\vert\ $, $\ \vert QM\vert = \vert RM\vert\ $, and $\ PM\ $ is common).  Therefore, the angles $\ \angle PMQ\ $ and $\ \angle PMR\ $ are equal, and since their sum is a straight angle of $180^{\large\circ}$, each of them must be a right angle.

A hint for the rest of the proof is to appeal to the similarity of the triangles $\ PLN\ $ and $\ PQR\ $.

Answer (score 0):

Since the triangles $PQR$ and $PLN$ have two sides congruent, they are isosceles triangles, so the angles $LPN$ and $RPQ$ are congruent and in each of the triangles you have the remaining angles are congruent. In particular, the angles $PLN$ and $PQR$ are congruent. Therefore $LN$ and $QR$ are parallel. Now, $PM$ is perpendicular to $QR$ because $R$ is the midpoint of the base. These two last facts have as consequence $PM$ is also perpendicular to $LN$.

Comment: Ok ok i got it. I prooved the triangles PMQ and PMR are congruent. So the angles PMR and PMQ are equal. As they both lie on a straight line in which the sum is 180 degrees, both the angles are 90 degrees. We also know that LN is parallel to QR and LN=1/2QR because of the midpoint theorem. As they are parallel we can say that the angle POL is equal to the angle PMQ because of corresponding angles. As PMQ is 90 degrees the angle POL is also 90 degrees which means LN is perpendicular to PM.

Comment: Is my way right ?

Comment: Yes. There are many ways. I choosed the shortest in my opinion. Your proof is a bit intricated, but it is logically okay. :)

Comment: Ok ok. In school this is the method they expect from us. By prooving it step by step. Thats why i tried this way after getting an idea from your method and others. Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: I have another doubt, that is if an angle in a triangle is bisected, will that bisector bisect the side of a triangle equally ?

Comment: Not necessarily, think about a scalene triangle with any bisector. This only works with isosceles triangles. Anyway: if you need to proof some theorems you should have demostrated before because you feel more confident, it is okay.